# Adding an Extra Empty Column While Reading An .xlsx file in PHP

Tags: php, excel

I edited a PHP code that reads an Excel Spreadsheet (.xlsx form) and displays it very well.
But I want an extra column to be added when PHP page displays the Spreadsheet. (For textareas to update one cell in each row.)

What can I do for it?

Thanks.

```
<?php
if((!empty($_FILES["file"])) && ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)) {

 $limitSize    = 15000000;

 require_once "simplexlsx.class.php";
 $getWorksheetName = array();
 $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
 $getWorksheetName = $xlsx->getWorksheetName();
 echo '    <hr>
 <div id="datacontent">
 ';



 '<div id="datacontent">';
 for($j=1;$j <= $xlsx->sheetsCount();$j++){
 echo '<h3>Tablodaki Worksheet: '.$getWorksheetName[$j-1].'</h1>';
 echo '<table id="xlsxTable">';
 list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension($j);
 foreach( $xlsx->rows($j+1) as $k => $r) {
 if ($k == 0){
 $trOpen        = '<th';
 $trClose    = '</th>';
 $tbOpen        = '<thead>';
 $tbClose    = '</thead>';
 }else{
 $trOpen        = '<td';
 $trClose    = '</td>';
 $tbOpen        = '<tbody>';
 $tbClose    = '</tbody>';
 }
 echo $tbOpen;
 echo '<tr>';
 for( $i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++)
 echo $trOpen.'>'.( (isset($r[$i])) ? $r[$i] : '&nbsp;' ).$trClose;
 echo '</tr>';
 echo $tbClose;
 }
 echo '</table>';
 }
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: If you need to write the xlsx file again with updates after you've read it, then you need a class that can actually write xlsx files as well, not simply read them

Comment: Yes I know, I will include another class for it but before that I must insert an extra column

Comment: Change for( $i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++) to for( $i = 0; $i <= $cols; $i++)

Comment: I tried it but it did not make any difference.